# How to manage number of migrations with Typeorm?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Apologies in advance as I am unable to find a good solution regarding this.

Background: We are using Typeorm in express app and have too many migrations because its a little old project.

Question: Is there a good way to manage migrations? Ideally I would want to delete all migrations(generated till now) and have only single file for schema creation(updated automatically after every migration run) and another file for seeding master data. Using these two files any new developer can setup the database locally in no time.

I worked in Ruby on rails and there used to be a clean approach like ruby maintains the database schema all the time in `schema.rb` and database could be generated using that.

I researched a lot but couldn't find a maintainable solution. May be the experts here could help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

All your schemas describe your data model at current time, you can just delete all migrations from code and database, it will be as if you had no migrations at all. The problem will be only with old versions of your database which needs to be migrated.